# How can I create a polar stair-step graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates

I wanted to create a polar stair-step graph. For example, let's say that I want to create a graph which can show the thermostat temperature set point for each 15 minutes time step (as for the data below) and the respective temperatures:

```
time       Therm 1   Therm 2
23          8        8
23:15      14.75    11.165
23:30      21.5     14.330
23:45      28.25    17.495
24:00:00   35       20.660
0:15:00    41.75    23.825
00:30      48.5     26.990
00:45               30.155
01:00               33.320
01:15               36.485
01:30               39.650
01:45               42.815
02:00               45.980
02:15               49.145
02:30               52.310
02:45               55.475
03:00               58.640
03:15               61.805
```

How it can be shown in a polar graph where the values from the center point to the perimeter show temperature while the points on the orbit show time (normally as a clock)?

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I'm using version: 8.2.0.701 (R2013b)  (a network licence)

Answer (score 0):

The following code assumes there are 12 hours on a clock face.

Summary:

1. Use basic arithmetic to calculate angle on the clock face.
2. Flip and rotate by 90 deg to get the real clock face. You can change XTicks to real clock numbers.
3. Use `stairs` to generate data needed by a stair plot, then use `polar` to plot it in a polar plot.

---

```
Data = [
23,00         , 8       , 8    ;
23,15      ,14.75    ,11.165;
23,30      ,21.5     ,14.330;
23,45      ,28.25    ,17.495;
24,00   ,35       ,20.660;
00,15    ,41.75    ,23.825;
00,30      ,48.5     ,26.990;
00,45      ,NaN       ,30.155;
01,00      ,NaN       ,33.320;
01,15      ,NaN       ,36.485;
01,30      ,NaN       ,39.650;
01,45      ,NaN       ,42.815;
02,00      ,NaN       ,45.980;
02,15      ,NaN       ,49.145;
02,30      ,NaN       ,52.310;
02,45      ,NaN       ,55.475;
03,00      ,NaN       ,58.640;
03,15      ,NaN       ,61.805;];

hours = Data(:,1);
minutes = Data(:,2);
T1 = Data(:,3);
T2 = Data(:,4);

theta = mod(hours+minutes/60,12)/12*2*pi;
theta = pi/2 - theta;

[xb2,yb2] = stairs(theta,T2);
[xb1,yb1] = stairs(theta,T1);
polar(xb2,yb2)
hold on
polar(xb1,yb1)
```

Comment: yes, that code works in the matlab, but it does not create a stair-step grap it only create two curves and not defined at which hour start and end.

Answer (score 0):

First, we'll start with the sample thermostat data from your question as an 18-by-2 matrix:

```
data = [8.0000 14.7500 21.5000 28.2500 35.0000 41.7500 48.5000 nan(1, 11); ...
        8.0000 11.1650 14.3300 17.4950 20.6600 23.8250 26.9900 30.1550 33.3200 ...
          36.4850 39.6500 42.8150 45.9800 49.1450 52.3100 55.4750 58.6400 61.8050].';
```

You'll want to define how many hours you will show on your clock face, which you can do by setting a value that will be used for all later calculations:

```
nHours = 12;  % Or 24 will work too
```

Getting your time data in the right format will depend on what you start with. If you start with an 18-by-1 [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) vector stored in `timeData`, do this:

```
tData = mod(timeData.Hour+timeData.Minute/60, nHours);
```

Or you can generate your vector from scratch like so:

```
tData = mod(23+(0:15:255).'./60, nHours);
```

You'll need to replicate values so the plot gives a stairstep effect. You can use the function [`stairs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html) to replicate `tData` and generate an index vector to replicate rows of your `data` matrix:

```
[tData, index] = stairs(tData, 1:numel(tData));
data = data(index, :);
```

Now, all the data is in the right format, and the best way to generate the polar plot will depend on what version of MATLAB you are running...

### For version R2016a or later:

You can plot the data using [`polarplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html), modify axes settings accordingly, and then add a [legend](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html):

```
p = polarplot(2.*pi.*tData./nHours, data);
set(gca, 'ThetaDir', 'clockwise', ...
         'ThetaZeroLocation', 'top', ...
         'ThetaTick', 360*(0:(nHours-1))./nHours, ...
         'ThetaTickLabel', cellstr(num2str((0:(nHours-1)).', '%02d:00')));
legend(p, {'Therm 1', 'Therm 2'});
```

And here's the plot:

[image]

### For versions prior to R2016a:

In versions without the `polarplot` function, the (now deprecated) function [`polar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html) has to be used. The plots it creates are notoriously difficult to modify (hence why it is now effectively obsolete), but we can get pretty close to reproducing the above plot with the following:

```
polar(2.*pi.*repmat(tData, [1 size(data, 2)])./nHours, data);
set(gca, 'XDir', 'reverse', 'CameraUpVector', [1 0 0]);
hText = findall(0, 'Type', 'text');
labelIndex = cellfun(@(s) ~isempty(s), regexp(get(hText, 'String'), '^\S+$'));
strValues = get(hText(labelIndex), 'String');
strValues = cellstr(num2str(nHours.*str2double(strValues)./360, '%02d:00'));
set(hText(labelIndex), {'String'}, strValues);
legend({'Therm 1', 'Therm 2'});
```

And here's the plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm trying to run the code in the matlab but I get this error: Attempted to access hours(23); index out of bounds because numel(hours)=18.  As you point out I need to replecate the values but not sure whre and how ?

Comment: @D_Marini: The problem you are having is that you have declared a variable called `hours`, and this is shadowing the *function* called `hours`. You need to name your variable something else, so that `hours(23)` calls the function instead of indexing the variable. In general, you should never use an existing function as a variable name.

Comment: I have just copied you code  in the matlab as follow: tData = mod(hours(hours(23)+minutes(0:15:255)), 24);

data = [8.0000 14.7500 21.5000 28.2500 35.0000 41.7500 48.5000 nan(1, 11); ...
        8.0000 11.1650 14.3300 17.4950 20.6600 23.8250 26.9900 30.1550 33.3200 ...
          36.4850 39.6500 42.8150 45.9800 49.1450 52.3100 55.4750 58.6400 61.8050]; 
      
index = repelem(1:numel(tData), 2);
tData = tData(index(2:end));
data = data(:, index(1:(end-1)));  And now the error is: Undefined function 'hours' for input arguments of type 'double'.  Not sure how it worked in your case ?

Comment: @D_Marini: You're using a much older version of MATLAB than me. The `hours` function was introduced in R2014b. Even worse, the `polarplot` function was introduced even later in R2016a, so this solution won't work for you. I'll see if I can figure out a workaround.

Comment: I tried to use "kron" function to repleace "repelem" as follow: index = kron(tData,ones(1,2));  and it produces the index values: 23 23 23.2500000000000 23.2500000000000 23.5000000000000 23.5000000000000 23.7500000000000 23.7500000000000 0 0 0.250000000000000 0.250000000000000 0.500000000000000 0.500000000000000 0.750000000000000 0.750000000000000 1 1 1.25000000000000 1.25000000000000 1.50000000000000 1.50000000000000 1.75000000000000 1.75000000000000 2 2 2.25000000000000 2.25000000000000 2.50000000000000 2.50000000000000 2.75000000000000 2.75000000000000 3 3 3.25000000000000 3.25000000000000

Comment: @D_Marini: You should apply `kron` to the vector `1:numel(tData)`, not `tData`.

Comment: this apparntly is not accep[ted from the matlab and gives the error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: thanks that works, trying to add the legend but not succesfully

Comment: @D_Marini: Added legends and improved the formatting a bit. Hope that helps!